# Windows Minimising to the Left Rather than the Dock

Tags: macos, window-manager, sonoma

When I minimise a window, instead of appearing in the dock, it is now appearing on the left. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to turn the behaviour back the way it was?

I'm using Sonoma 14.1.2.

Answer (score 0):

That's because of Stage Manager, you can disable it in the Control Centre.

[image]